# Shopify Quiz app or gateway with individual link / password for customers that can't be easily shared

Tags: shopify, payment-gateway

I am looking to use a quiz platform like Presido Quiz kit or involve.me. and set it up as a digital product on Shopify that once paid, the customer will receive the link to complete the quiz and get their result or complete the quiz and pay to receive the result.

I've not heard  from Preside if the above is possible. With involve.me it's possible for customers to pay for the quiz however the link can be shared on once they have access to it. I can password protect the link, however, this will be the same password for every customer which means that the quiz can still be shared. Their platform does not offer individual links or password for each customer.

Is there any gateway I can put in place or an alternative platform that will help achieve my goal.

Thanks,